# xrandr says that my recently created mode is an unrecognized option when trying to add it to my moniter

Tags: nvidia, display, xrandr, display-resolution

my moniter is actually a small tv and does in fact support 1080p although currently uibuntu says that the highest i can go up to is 1360x768. created a mode named 1080p that i can see when using command "xrandr" that does in fact have the correct resolution although im not sure if im just doing some thing stupid cuz this is my first real install not on a vm.

what ive done so far:

1: `cvt 1920 1080 60`
2: `xrandr --newmode "1080p"` (I copied the modeline) produced by cvt i can now see my mode when i use xrandr
3: `xrandr --addmode Screen 0 1080p`
OUTPUT: xrandr: unrecognized option '1080p'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your last command.

- Detect you monitor name with `xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'` and replace it for the `Screen` option.
- Don't use `0` - you don't need that.

So the command would look like this:

```
xrandr --addmode MonitorName 1080p
```

Comment: It now gives me this evan@Neb:~$ xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
HDMI-0
evan@Neb:~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1080p
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  46

Comment: i also just tried straight up xrandr -s 1080p and the output was                     size index is too large there are only 9 sizes.

Comment: @NebulousFox unfortunately there isn't a solution to that error... I'm in the progress of finding out why it happens and what can fix it - if I do find a solution, I'll tell you **=)**

Comment: alright haha sounds good thank you. and by the way how do you comment with the formatting for displaying code the way you did?

Comment: @NebulousFox you can use ``, <pre></pre> or indent your code by 4 spaces